# Let $f(x) = \frac {px + q }{x + r}$ where x ∈ R \ {-r, r}. If f(x) = f(-x) for all x, show that $f(x) = p$ for x ∈ R \ {-r, r}

Tags: functions, relations

Let $f(x) = \frac {px + q }{x + r}$ where $x \in \mathbb R\setminus \{-r, r\}$. If $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all x, show that $f(x) = p$ for $x \in \mathbb R\setminus \{-r, r\}$

I've been working on this question for a while and haven't made any progress.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As a way to get started:  Suppose $-\frac qp$ is in the domain of this function.  Deduce that $q=0$ and conclude from there.  If, on the other hand, $-\frac qp$ is not in the domain, what can you conclude?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you have $\frac {px + q}{x+r} = \frac {-px + q}{-x +r}$ for all $x\ne \pm r$.

Cross multiply and you get $(px+q)(-x+r) = (-px+q)(x+r)$

Can you finish?

Alternative what happens if you let $x = 1$?  $x= 2$?

Alternatively $\frac {px + q}{x+r}= \frac {px +pr + (q-pr)}{x+r}= p + \frac {q-pr}{x+r}$.

So we must have $f(x) = p + \frac {q-pr}{x+r}$ and $f(-x) = p +\frac {q-pr}{-x+r}$.  So $\frac {q-pr}{x+r} = \frac {q-pr}{-x+r}$ for *ALL* $x$ (except $r$).   What does that tell us?

> $-px^2 -qx + rpx + rq = -px^2 +qx-rpx +rq$ so

> $-qx + rpx=-(qx-rpx) = qx - rpx$.  That's only possible if $qx -rpx = 0$. But if $qx-rpx = x(q-rp) = 0$ then either $x=0$ or $q-rp = 0$. But if this is true for all $x$ except $\pm r$ then it is true for some non-zero $x$.  So $q-rp = 0$ and $a=rp$.

> So $f(x) = \frac {px + rp}{x+r} = \frac{p(x+r)}{x+r}=p$.  A constant